# Python elasticsearch-dsl build match query dynamically

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-dsl-py

Using `ElasticSearch 6.x` and [elasticsearch-dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) python package

I am trying to generate a `match` query with its `options` form, with the `query` element.

I have a list of fields `fields = ['field_1', 'field_2']` and I am trying to build a leaf `match` query using the following method

```
from elasticsearch_dsl.query import MultiMatch, Match, ConstantScore

def _get_match(tokens, fields, boost):        
        for index in range(len(fields)):
                field = fields[index]
                print(Match(field={"query": tokens[index], "boost": boost}))


tokens = ['token_1', 'token_2']
fields = ['field_1', 'field_2']
boost = 3
_get_match(tokens, fields, boost)
```

Generated output:

```
Match(field={'query': 'token_1', 'boost': 3})
Match(field={'query': 'token_2', 'boost': 3})
```

Expected output:

```
Match(field_1={'query': 'token_1', 'boost': 3})
Match(field_2={'query': 'token_2', 'boost': 3})
```

Notice, the field values instead of the field values passed in the array, the query generated used the variable name directly. How can I generate the Match query dynamically?

If I use the `**` as mentioned in this [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30900337/dynamic-queries-in-elasticsearch-and-issue-of-keywords) it does create a dynamic query but it is in the simplified format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already mentioned the `**` for unpacking a dictionary. Works fine, I only changed one line:

```
print(Match(** {field: {"query": tokens[index], "boost": boost}}))
```

Comment: oh yea, silly me, I could have unpacked the dictionary and included other fields directly into that. Thanks a lot for making it clear.

Comment: @inxss, I'm glad I could help. In case this solved your problem, please consider marking it as the correct answer :) Thanks!